Pytorch DataLoader index out of bounds
I have a dataset with high class imbalance. So to create proper training and testing sets, I have decided to use StratifiedShuffleSplit and a weighted sampler to improve training.
dataset = ImageFolder(root='/path/to/directory', transform=transform)

#stratified split

ss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.5, train_size=0.5)
# ss.get_n_splits() #arguments - input features, target labels
for train_idx, test_idx in ss.split(np.zeros(len(dataset.targets)),dataset.targets):
    train_dataset = Subset(dataset, train_idx)
    test_dataset = Subset(dataset, test_idx)

#sampler
targets_tensor = torch.tensor(dataset.targets, device = device)
targets_array = targets_tensor.cpu().numpy()
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes = np.unique(targets_array), y=targets_array)
class_weights = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float32, device = device)

sample_weights = np.zeros(len(targets_array))
for idx, label in enumerate(targets_array):
    sample_weights[idx] = class_weights[label]

sample_weights = torch.from_numpy(sample_weights).to(device)
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(weights=sample_weights, num_samples=len(sample_weights), replacement=True)



    
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, sampler = sampler)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32, sampler = sampler)


Now during training, when I attempt to start the loop, I get this error-
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[71], line 5
      2 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
      3     # running_loss = 0.0
      4     i = 0
----> 5     for images,labels in train_loader:
      6         # if image is from an index other than trainset_
      8         w, h = images.size(2), images.size(3)
      9         optimizer.zero_grad()

File ~/test2/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:631, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    628 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    629     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    630     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 631 data = self._next_data()
    632 self._num_yielded += 1
    633 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    634         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    635         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/test2/virtual/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:675, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    673 def _next_data(self):
    674     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 675     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
...
    417     return self.dataset.__getitems__([self.indices[idx] for idx in indices])  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    418 else:
--> 419     return [self.dataset[self.indices[idx]] for idx in indices]

IndexError: index 6057 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4544
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

Whhen I load the entire dataset instead of the subset, it works perfectly.
I think I understand that the Loader is calling the extracted 'label' from the train_dataset. But I want it to extract the labels that are present in the train_loader from the parent dataset.
Is there any way I can do this?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

@furas I have edited my message to include the entire error message
